# find nearest Gps point to the user location form a list

Tags: java, android, database, location

what i am trying to do: the user selects start and destination on a map and then from their coordinates i want to show the closest point location from a list of locations on map. i have a simple Sqlite database containing the longitude,latitude and name of the possible locations.

i did some research and this is what i found:

http://www.scribd.com/doc/2569355/Geo-Distance-Search-with-MySQL

but this is meant for using it with mySql and some kind of spatial search extension. 
is there a possibility i can do something similar using android api or external libs?

```
public Point dialogFindClosestLocationToPoint(geometry.Point aStartPoint){
List<PointWithDistance> helperList=new ArrayList<PointWithDistance>();
try {
openDataBase();
Cursor c=getCursorQueryWithAllTheData();
if(c.moveToFirst())
 do{
  PointWithDistance helper=new PointWithDistance(c.getDouble(1),c.getDouble(2),c.getString(3));
  int distance=returnDistanceBetween2Points(aStartPoint, helper);
  if(distance<MAX_SEARCH_DISTANCE){
   helper.setDistance(distance);
   Log.i("values", helper.name);
   helperList.add(helper);
  }
 }while (c.moveToNext());
Collections.sort(helperList,new PointComparator());

if(helperList!=null)
 return helperList.get(0);
else return null;
}catch(SQLException sqle){

throw sqle;

}
finally{
 close();
}
```

this is the code in the PointComparator() class:

```
   public int compare(PointWithDistance o1, PointWithDistance o2) {
  return (o1.getDistance()<o2.getDistance() ? -1 : (o1.getDistance()==o2.getDistance() ? 0 : 1));
 }
```

where `PointWithDistance` is a object that contains: lat, long , distance, name

however this solution doesn't provide the right return info... and i realize that is it not scalable at all and very slow. i need a solution that will execute fast with a database with max of 1000 rows.

edit: my there was a mistake in this code in the sorting now i have it changed( should be < instead of >)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for something very similar some time ago:

[Android sqlite sort on calculated column (co-ordinates distance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034348/android-sqlite-sort-on-calculated-column-co-ordinates-distance)

I was using a MySQL lookup on my server, MySQL allows you to create a virtual column, performs the calculation and sorts by distance, and then you can set the max results returned or the max distance - it works very well:

```
Select Lat, Lon, acos(sin($lat)*sin(radians(Lat)) + cos($lat)*cos(radians(Lat))cos(radians(Lon)-$lon))$R As dist From MyTable ORDER BY dist DESC
```

I wanted to perform the same operation in my app - pull all the points in order to distance from the users location allowing me to show the closest ones. I ended up going with the a solution along the lines of the one suggested on the link above but realise its probably not the optimal solution but works for the purpose I wanted.

Comment: I believe that you have been passing variables throught php. $lat is your current latitude, $lon is current latitude. But what is $R ?

Comment: Isn't $R the earth radius? see: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Answer (score 3):

This kind of thing is done most efficiently using an [R-Tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rtree). The [JSI library](http://github.com/aled/jsi) provides a Java implementation that I have used successfully with an index of 80.000 locations, processing thousands of lookups per second. However, it may not run on Android.

Comment: yes i found some info that r-tree is a pretty good solution for this but i haven't found any library for android so far to work with. i'll keep looking and try the mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

i haven't tried running your code, but it seems like it would work, it's just that it's not efficient. like you don't actually need to sort, you need the extract the minimum.

you can restrict your query to just the square that is of size (2*MAX_SEARCH_DISTANCE)^2 (with your point in the middle.
This way you are localizing your query and that will return you less results to compute distance for.
Of course this will not help if all your locations are in the localized square (maybe unlikely?).

Also, I suppose you could use hamiltonian distance instead of euclidean.
euclidean distance = sqrt((lat0 - lat1)^2 + (lon0 - lon1)^2)
hamitonian distance = (lat0 - lat1) + (lon0 - lon1)

Comment: i am actually using the function defined in the Android Location api to calculate distance between two gps coordinates. as i found out it is very precise and it takes the shape of the earth also into account. "you need the extract the minimum." what is the best way to do that?